# extracting data from xml tree file with python

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file which has some test limits that I want to extract and write to xls file.

```
<TestLimitSet>
<AppName>Test Application</AppName>
<Name>High-Speed test app</Name>
<SummaryName>limit set 1.0</SummaryName>
<SharedReference>DUT Specification Version 1.0</SharedReference>
<TestLimits>
    <!--########## Host Electrical Specification ##########-->
    <!--Host Strobe Frequency-->
    <TestLimit>
        <ID>1101, 1102</ID>
        <SummaryName>Host Strobe Frequency</SummaryName>
        <SummaryDescription>The frequency must within the specification.</SummaryDescription>
        <Reference>Section 3.</Reference>
        <PrecisionLevel>0.01E+6</PrecisionLevel>
        <PassLimits>
            <Type>RANGE_INCLUSIVE</Type>
            <Min>239.88E+6</Min>
            <Max>240.12E+6</Max>
        </PassLimits>
    </TestLimit>

    <!--Host Data Slew Rate-->
    <TestLimit>
        <ID>1201</ID>
        <SummaryName>Host Data Slew Rate</SummaryName>
        <SummaryDescription>Slew rate must within the specification.</SummaryDescription>
        <Reference>Section 4.</Reference>
        <PrecisionLevel>0.001</PrecisionLevel>
        <PassLimits>
            <Type>RANGE_INCLUSIVE</Type>
            <Min>0.7</Min>
            <Max>2.0</Max>
        </PassLimits>
    </TestLimit>

    <!--Host Strobe Slew Rate-->
    <TestLimit>
        <ID>1202</ID>
        <SummaryName>Host Strobe Slew Rate</SummaryName>
        <SummaryDescription>Slew rate must within the specification.</SummaryDescription>
        <Reference>Section 5.</Reference>
        <PrecisionLevel>0.001</PrecisionLevel>
        <PassLimits>
            <Type>RANGE_INCLUSIVE</Type>
            <Min>0.7</Min>
        </PassLimits>
    </TestLimit>

</TestLimits>
```

I use the following python code to extract the data:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
document = ElementTree.parse( 'limitset.lim' )
#
for testname in document.findall( 'TestLimits/TestLimit/SummaryName' ):
    print 'TestName:', testname.text
    limits = document.find( 'TestLimits/TestLimit/PassLimits' )
    for node in limits.getchildren():
        print node.tag, node.text
```

And this is the output:

```
TestName: Host Strobe Frequency
Type RANGE_INCLUSIVE
Min 239.88E+6
Max 240.12E+6
TestName: Host Data Slew Rate
Type RANGE_INCLUSIVE
Min 239.88E+6
Max 240.12E+6
TestName: Host Strobe Slew Rate
Type RANGE_INCLUSIVE
Min 239.88E+6
Max 240.12E+6
```

The problem is that the "Min" and "Max" always come from the first node in XML instead of the appropriate section under the test name. Can someone help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using `document.find` in the loop - it returns the same node each time. You should go this way:

```
for limit in document.findall('TestLimits/TestLimit'):
    testname = limit.find('.//SummaryName')
    print 'TestName:', testname.text
    limits = limit.find('.//PassLimits')
    for node in limits.getchildren():
        print node.tag, node.text
```